# What does $z\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

I am reading about the Siegel Center Problem and I came across a paper that uses notation I am not familiar with. They say,

> In this paper, we study the Siegel center problem. Consider two subalgebras
>   $A_1 \subset A_2$ of $z\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ closed with respect to the composition of formal series. For example, $z\mathbb{C}[[z]]$, $z\mathbb{C}\{z\}$ (the usual analytic case), ...

I am specifically studying the center problem in the analytic case i.e. for
holomorphic functions, $$f(z) = \lambda z + a_2z^2 + a_3z^3 + ...$$
which are defined throughout some neighbourhood of the origin, with a fixed point of multiplier $\lambda$ at the origin.

Source: http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_2000__128_1_69_0.pdf (free access)

Comment: $z \mathbb{C}[[z]]$ is the set $\{z \cdot f(z) : f(z) \in \mathbb{C}[[z]]\}$; that is, the elements of $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ multiplied by $z$.

Comment: Probably formal power series without a constant term.

Comment: To put a paragraph in a blockquote, all you need to do is put a `>` at the beginning of the paragraph.  I took the liberty of doing this for you. I also removed your post-script. :)

Comment: @user296602 What is $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ then?

Comment: It's the [ring of formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_ring_of_formal_power_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ represents the set of formal power series with complex coefficient in the variable $z$, endowed with the "obvious" ring structure.  That is,
$$ \mathbb{C}[[z]] := \left\{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n z^n : \alpha_n \in \mathbb{C} \right\}, $$
where addition and multiplication are defined in the way that you would expect from finite series, i.e.
$$ \sum \alpha_n z^n + \sum \beta_n z^n = \sum (\alpha_n + \beta_n) z^n $$
and
$$ \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n z^n \right) \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \beta_n z^n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \alpha_k \beta_{n-k} z^n. $$

Informally, the notation $z \mathbb{C}[[z]]$ denotes the subset of formal power series that we get by multiplying every element of $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ by $z$.  With slightly more rigor, 
\begin{align}
z\mathbb{C}[[z]] &:= \left\{ z \cdot S : S \in \mathbb{C}[[z]] \right\} \\
&= \left\{ z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n z^n : \alpha_n \in \mathbb{C} \right\} \\
&= \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n z^{n} : \alpha_n \in \mathbb{C} \right\}.
\end{align}
Note that this corresponds to the set of formal power series without a constant term.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ is the ring of formal power series in $z$, $z \mathbb{C}[[z]]$ is the set of power series with zero constant term. In particular, it consists of elements of the form

$$b_1 z + b_2 z^2 + b_3 z^3 + \cdots$$

with $b_k \in \mathbb{C}$ for all $k \ge 1$.